# Splitting string doesn't give expected output

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a given string according to the given format ->  `,;:.?!` .What I am doing is given below, but whenever it is encountering more than 1 space it is adding space to the array. I just want the word not the space.

**INPUT::**
`hello Hello HEllo hi hi: hi! Welcome,   welcome`

**OUTPUT::**
13
hello
Hello
HEllo
hi
hi

hi

Welcome

welcome

**EXPECTED OUTPUT::**
*8

hello

Hello

HEllo

hi

hi

hi

Welcome

welcome*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        String[] arr = s.split("[ ,;:.?!]");
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        for (String string : arr) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexp matching only 1 character, you can add `{1,2}` to it so it would match 1 or 2 characters, or you can even replace it with `+` to match 1 or more.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        String[] arr = s.split("[ ,;:.?!]{1,2}");
        System.out.println(arr.length);
        for (String string : arr) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try trimming the string.

```
System.out.println(string.trim());
```

Or, like others said, you can escape the whitespace character like this:

```
String[] arr = s.split("[\\s+,;:.?!]");
```